# JavaScript / D3.js: Data is not updating when button is clicked, new positions are being plotted instead

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, append, bar-chart

When a button is clicked both the red woman (unvaccinated) and the blue woman (vaccinated) should be updated to reflect the new value. Currently on button click the red woman updates but the blue woman is recreated on the location that it should be updated to. How can I get the blue woman to transition and update like the red woman?

Here you can see where the blue woman is recreated:
[image: Here you can see where the blue woman is recreated]

**I created two global variables:**

```
 var numOfPartner = 'zero';
 var status = 0;
```

**Here is where the on load data is being created and the red image is being introduced:**

```
d3.csv("link to data", function(error, data) {

    if (error) {
      console.log("error reading file");
    }

    data.sort(function(a, b) {
      return d3.descending(+a.status, +b.status);
    });

    // you should calculate using d3.max for your data
    widthScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return +d.start;
    })]);

    heightScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {
      return +d.average;
    }).slice(1));

    var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(([data[0]]))
    .enter()
    .append("rect");

    rects
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return heightScale(d.status);
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return widthScale(+d.average);
      })
      .attr("height", heightScale.rangeBand());

    svg.selectAll("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .data(([data[0]]))
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return +d.average + " %";
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return widthScale(+d.average) + 5;
      })
      .attr('y', '-45')
      .attr("fill", "#8a8c8e")
      .attr("font-size", "24")
      .attr("font-weight", "700")

    // Style the axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .attr("fill", "#808285");

    // Label below x axis
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "xlabel")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + " ," +
            height + ")")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("dy", "0")
      .text("  ")
      .attr("fill", "#5582b0")
      .attr("font-weight", "600");

    svg.selectAll("image1")
      .data(([data[0]]))
      .enter()
      .append("svg:image")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return widthScale(+d.average) - 45;
      })
      .attr('y', '-40')
      .attr("height", 200)
      .attr("width", 115)
      .attr("xlink:href", "link to red woman");
```

**Here is the function for the button update where the red woman works but the blue does not:**

```
d3.selectAll("button").on("click", function() {
     if (this.id == "unvaccinated")
         status = 0;
     else if (this.id == "vaccinated") {
         status = 1;
     } else {
         numOfPartner = this.id;
     }
     svg.selectAll("image2")
         .data(([data[1]]))
         .enter()
         .append("svg:image")
         .attr("x", function(d) {
             return widthScale(data[1][numOfPartner]) - 45;
         })
         .attr('y', '-40')
         .attr("height", 200)
         .attr("width", 115)
         .attr("xlink:href", "link to blue woman");

     rects
         .data(data)
         .transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .ease("linear")
         .attr("width", function(d) {
             return widthScale(data[status][numOfPartner]);
         });

     svg.selectAll("text")
         .data(([data[0]]))
         .transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .ease("linear")
         .attr("x", function(d) {
             return widthScale(data[status][numOfPartner])
         })
         .text(function(d) {
             return data[status][numOfPartner] + " %"
         });

     svg.selectAll("image")
         .data(([data[0]]))
         .transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .ease("linear")
         .attr("x", function(d) {
             //get correct number     
             return widthScale(data[status][numOfPartner]) - 45;
         });


     svg.selectAll("image2")
         .data(([data[1]]))
         .transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .ease("linear")
         .attr("x", function(d) {
             //get correct number     
             return widthScale(data[1][numOfPartner]) - 45;
         });

     });

});
```

I have tried to play with the on button click function as well as the data being pulled but I have not had any luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say 100% what is wrong without seeing the data or a live demo, but I can see an issue in the click callback. Move this code to the `d3.csv` callback:

```
 svg.selectAll("image2")
     .data(([data[1]]))
     .enter()
     .append("svg:image")
     .attr("x", function(d) {
         return widthScale(data[1][numOfPartner]) - 45;
     })
     .attr('y', '-40')
     .attr("height", 200)
     .attr("width", 115)
     .attr("xlink:href", "link to blue woman");
```

This adds a new element to your SVG rather than making an update. This is likely not what you want in the click callback. This should go in an initialization function somewhere. You have the correct update code later in the callback, but this will not work as expected because a new element has been added.

One other thing, I noticed you use `image1` in the data callback, and `image1` in the click callback. Make sure this is correct and not a typo.